# Grammar xtext (eclipse modeling) and react native

Tags: javascript, eclipse, react-native, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I try to create a grammar Dsl (xtext) to generate react native code, I have no idea how to declare the elements in my grammar (checkBox, list ....).

Thanks for helping me .

Comment: do you have any imagination how you syntax should look like? this question does not show what your actual problem is

Comment: For exemple ,In a  grammar  used  to generate an android application, I declare a checkbox as follows:

Comment: lokks like your comment got lost

Comment: For exemple ,In a  grammar  used  to generate an android application, I declare a checkbox as follows:                                                                                                                                                                                      ""CheckBox:  
'checkBox'  (name=ID)?
 '(' text=STRING ')' ('[''id' id =INT ('width' width=INT 'height' height=INT 'style' 
   style=STRING  )?']' );  ""
But in a grammar that follows the syntax react native ,I have no idea about ​​the properties of a checkBox (the same thing for list radioButton ....)

Comment: i still do not understand. what is your question/problem

Comment: My grammar:  Vue:
 
 'page' name=ID  '{'elements+=Element+'}'; 
 
Element: 
 Container | Component; 
 
Container: 
 Layout |  ListView | Tableau;  
 
Component:  
 TextView | Input | Label | RadioButton | CheckBox | Button   ; 
 
Layout:
  'layout' (name=ID)? '['type =STRING orientation=STRING title=STRING 'id' id =INT ('width' width=INT 'height' height=INT 'style' 
   style=STRING  )?']'
 '{'elements+=Element*'}';     
In my project, I have to create a grammar xtext, so I don't know how to adapt my xtext grammar to generate native react  , 
I was able to explain a little !!

Comment: i dont understand why you mean by "adapt grammar" and "generate native react". with the xtext grammar (AST + Concrete Syntax) and Generators are two different things. You create your grammar (and with it the AST) and then implement `MyDslGenerator` to output text in whatever format and syntax your want (in your case this would be a react java script code file - or whatever the react files actually are)

Comment: Yes I will create my xtext grammar and then my teacher has forced me to use sirius to generate a graphical representation, and then generate react native code ,Now I am still in the creation of my grammar and after that I will look for how to automatically generate the code from the model sirius .... what I understand is that the grammar remains the same for Any code I want to generate ??! Thans very much sir.

Comment: tge grammar is what you model. its your domain. its the same if you generate react, swift, android, java swt/awt/swing or c#

Comment: OKkkk, 
But I still have not understood one thing ,react native offers elements like  SearchBar,  SideMenu,  for exemple buttons, we found: SocialIcon, Button, IconButton so how to do this??  
Before I declare a button as follows: Button:
'Button' (name = ID)?
'(' Text = STRING ')' ('[' id 'id = INT (' width 'width =
Style = STRING)? ']');
 Because I had only one type of buttons but now I don't know how to add and define SocialIcon (SideMenu .....) in other words add the new elements proposed by react native to my grammar.

Comment: Here is the link that I see now : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements

Comment: that a question of grammar design !?! and you are the guy who is deisgning the grammar. you could use e.g. an enum in xtext

Comment: e.g: SocialIcon: type=SocialIconType title=STRING; enum SocialIconType: twitter | medium | facebook | ...;

Comment: Ahhhhh okkk ,now I understand
 Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xtext Grammar and Generators are not the same thing.

1. In the Xtext Grammar you define the "what". This means you define the concrete Syntax and the AST.
2. In the Generator you define how the AST is translated to text (in you case react js)

Have a look at the features Xtext offers you do use e.g. Attributes, (Cross/Containment)References and Enums

```
SocialIcon: 
    type=SocialIconType title=STRING; 
enum SocialIconType: 
    twitter | medium | facebook | ...;
```

Comment: Good evening to all , I always try to create a grammar Dsl (xtext). My grammar must contain a model part, a view part and a controller part And as a follow-up to my last questionn concerning the view of my grammar.
My question now concerns the controller in which I have to define the events (onClique ...) so I have not found how to do this. examples or tutorials on the MVC model in xtext grammar thnks for helping me ...

Comment: I don't get that point. The question is not how to do MVc in Xtext the question is how to express mvc. And then you can ask: this is my concrete syntax. How can I do that with Xtext